# cocos2d-x 2.2.3 + XCode 5.1.1 + CCEditBox --> undefined symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm using cocos2d-x-2.2.3 with xcode to develop an app for iOs. I copied SimpleGame project under samples and I've added a CCEditBox, adding #include "extensions/cocos-ext.h"

It compiles but fails to link due to extensions (see output below).

So I guess the extensions are not on libcocos2dx.a, but I don't know how to compile them or where to find the library. Additionally, I'm new to XCode and I'm not sure on how to add libraries, since libcocos2d.a doesn't show up on Build Phases or Build Settings.

The app compiles and works fine without the CCEditBox.

```
Ld /Users/monso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BattleChess-amsjjdvrzqgtqudosumuxdqfgazj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BattleChess.app/BattleChess normal i386
cd /Users/monso/code/android/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/samples/Cpp/BattleChess/proj.ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/monso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BattleChess-amsjjdvrzqgtqudosumuxdqfgazj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/monso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BattleChess-amsjjdvrzqgtqudosumuxdqfgazj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/monso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BattleChess-amsjjdvrzqgtqudosumuxdqfgazj/Build/Intermediates/BattleChess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BattleChess.build/Objects-normal/i386/BattleChess.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -fobjc-link-runtime -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 /Users/monso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BattleChess-amsjjdvrzqgtqudosumuxdqfgazj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2dx.a -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework OpenAL -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGLES -lxml2 -lz -framework QuartzCore -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/monso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BattleChess-amsjjdvrzqgtqudosumuxdqfgazj/Build/Intermediates/BattleChess.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BattleChess.build/Objects-normal/i386/BattleChess_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/monso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BattleChess-amsjjdvrzqgtqudosumuxdqfgazj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BattleChess.app/BattleChess

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"cocos2d::ui::Margin::Margin()", referenced from:
___cxx_global_var_init4 in AppDelegate.o
___cxx_global_var_init4 in IntroScene.o
"cocos2d::extension::CCScale9Sprite::create(char const*)", referenced from:
IntroLayer::init() in IntroScene.o
"cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::setFontColor(cocos2d::_ccColor3B const&)", referenced from:
IntroLayer::init() in IntroScene.o
"cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::setMaxLength(int)", referenced from:
IntroLayer::init() in IntroScene.o
"cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::setReturnType(cocos2d::extension::KeyboardReturnType)", referenced from:
IntroLayer::init() in IntroScene.o
"cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::setPlaceHolder(char const*)", referenced from:
IntroLayer::init() in IntroScene.o
"cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::create(cocos2d::CCSize const&, cocos2d::extension::CCScale9Sprite*, cocos2d::extension::CCScale9Sprite*, cocos2d::extension::CCScale9Sprite*)", referenced from:
IntroLayer::init() in IntroScene.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: when I include, I dont do the `../` I am doing: `#include "cocos2d.h"`
`#include "extensions/cocos-ext.h"`

Comment: I've added cocos2d-x/extensions and cocos2d-x/ to the search path and now it works without the ''../''. The problem at linking remains, of course.